# Oracle and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, database, oracle, data-access

What client should be used to access Oracle database (specifically invoking the stored procedures) from ASP.net code? I am specifically referring to the industry standard. What tips/tricks/issues have you had with it?

EDITED

Comment: This is a Q&A site not a survey site. Having a thousand answers to a question is not what this is modelled for.

Comment: @Gary, I have to disagree. There can't be thousand answers to a question which specifically asks about **the** industry standard. There can only be one otherwise it wouldn't be standard. I think the question could be answered without being subjective.

Comment: You should rephrase your question to make it better. Try with: Which client should I use to access Oracle DB? Or which one is most commonly used. And ask people to input some issues they had with it. (But I voted for reopening). Rephrase and it will likely get reopened. Nothing unusual.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use [ODP.NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html).

[System.Data.OracleClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.aspx) which is part of the .NET framework [is deprecated](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/15/system-data-oracleclient-update.aspx) and should no longer be used because they will be removed in a future version of the .NET Framework.

Comment: Thank you Darin. Very useful. Is it widely supported by Oracle and MS? We now have our own class written awhile back and we want to make sure that if and when we switch, it will not be something that is/will be obsolete.

Comment: @gnomixa, yes, that's what [Microsoft suggests](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2009/06/15/system-data-oracleclient-update.aspx): `We strongly recommend customers to use  our partners' ADO.NET Provider for Oracle  instead of continuing to use Microsoft’s OracleClient for new application development`.

Comment: +1.. I never knew about this.. +1 to the question too for asking this seemingly innocuous question